# Load Location in Google Map on href Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to load Google different coordinates on href click. For Example

```
<a href="#location1">Location 1</a>
<a href="#location2">Location 2</a>
<a href="#location3">Location 3</a>
```

Below this there is a DIV which loads the Google Map which loads the locations from the above links.

```
<div id="map-container" class="col-md-12 no-gutter" style="height:500px;"></div>
```

Here is the script which is loading the Map with single location.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.520904, -0.107466),
                zoom: 17,
                draggable: false,
                scrollwheel: false,
                disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                zoomControl: false
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),
                mapOptions);

            var styles = [
                {
                    featureType: "landscape.man_made",
                    elementType: "geometry",
                    stylers: [
                        { visibility: "on" },
                        { color: "#d4ebf4" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    featureType: "road",
                    elementType: "labels.text.fill",
                    stylers: [
                        { visibility: "on" },
                        { color: "#202020"}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    featureType: "poi.business",
                    elementType: "all",
                    stylers: [
                        { visibility: "on" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    featureType: "poi.park",
                    elementType: "all",
                    stylers: [
                        { color: "#98d1e8" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    featureType: "poi.school",
                    elementType: "all",
                    stylers: [
                        { visibility: "off" },
                        { color: "#808080" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    featureType: "all",
                    elementType: "geometry.stroke",
                    stylers: [
                        { visibility: "off" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    featureType: "poi.park",
                    elementType: "labels.text.fill",
                    stylers: [
                        { visibility: "off" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    featureType: "transit.station.rail",
                    elementType: "labels.icon",
                    stylers: [
                        { hue: "#005eff" },
                        { saturation: -37 }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    featureType: "poi.park",
                    elementType: "labels.text.stroke",
                    stylers: [
                        { color: "#808080" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    featureType: "road.local",
                    elementType: "all",
                    stylers: [
                        { color: "#ffffff" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    featureType: "all",
                    elementType: "labels.text.fill",
                    stylers: [
                        { color: "#808080" }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    featureType: "transit.line",
                    elementType: "all",
                    stylers: [
                        { color: "#ffffff" }
                    ]
                }
            ];

            map.setOptions({styles: styles});


            var blueIco = {
                url: "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/map-pin.png",
                size: new google.maps.Size(55, 73),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(28, 72)
            };

            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.520904, -0.107466);

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: latLng,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                icon: blueIco,
                normalIcon: blueIco
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function (event) {
                this.setIcon(this.normalIcon);
                infowindow.close();
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Where do you get the coordinates from for the three additional locations?

Comment: related question: [Google Maps Onclick panTo new location Too Much Recursion error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127344/google-maps-onclick-panto-new-location-too-much-recursion-error)

Comment: I have added the above mentioned code panTo but pointer is not showing on after clicking on the location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use some Google map API to make it easier. like

### [Maplace](http://maplacejs.com/)

Here is a

### [Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/invincibleking77/pen/qEGRQq)

and the code:

### HTML

```
<div id="gmap"></div>

<div id="menu">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="loc_link" data-lat="12.58" data-long="77.38" data-title="Bangalore" data-html="Bangalore, Karnataka, India">A</a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="loc_link" data-lat="31.2" data-long="121.5" data-title="Shanghai" data-html="Shanghai, China">B</a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="loc_link" data-lat="35.6895" data-long="139.6917" data-title="Tokyo" data-html="Tokyo, Japan">C</a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="loc_link" data-lat="28.6139" data-long="77.2089" data-title="New Delhi" data-html="New Delhi, India">D</a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="loc_link" data-lat="40.7127" data-long="74.0059" data-title="New York" data-html="New York City">E</a>

 <br/>
  <span id="tool_tip">Click links to see effect!</span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#gmap{
width: 70%;
height: 350px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu {
 width: 300px;
 margin: 15px auto;
 text-align:center;
}
#menu a.loc_link {
 background: #0f89cf;
 color: #fff;
 margin-right: 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 padding: 5px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#menu span#tool_tip {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

### JQuery

```
$(function(){
var map;
var LocA = [{
    lat: 12.58,
    lon: 77.38,
    title: 'Bangalore',
    html: 'Bangalore, Karnataka, India',
    zoom: 4,
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/markerA.png',
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
 }];

map = new Maplace({
  locations: LocA,
  map_div: '#gmap',
  generate_controls: false,
  start: 0   
}).Load();


$(".loc_link").click(function(){
  var newLoc = [{
      lat: $(this).data('lat'),
      lon: $(this).data('long'),
      title: $(this).data('title'),
      html: $(this).data('html'),
      zoom: 4,
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/marker'+$(this).text()+'.png',
    animation:google.maps.Animation.DROP
  }];
 map.AddLocations(newLoc).Load();
 map.ViewOnMap($(this).index()+1);
});
});
```

Comment: You need to add these two js libraries to make it work
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry&v=3.13
http://maplacejs.com/src/maplace-0.1.3.min.js

Comment: I have added the above script and it's working but I want to modify a bit.. When you click on Location 1 it shows on map but when you click on the second it just shows the default location which is set in "LocA"..

Comment: i didn't get you. you mean when you click on new link its location is not added in the map? i think it is..

Comment: if you need to change the default location(means trigger a new location) on map, use "viewOnMap(index)" method. check the maplace documentation here: http://maplacejs.com/ (check doc tab)...You can also see a live demo on how to change the default location on google map here: http://codepen.io/invincibleking77/pen/vEyXxo

Answer (score 0):

related question: [Google Maps Onclick panTo new location Too Much Recursion error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127344/google-maps-onclick-panto-new-location-too-much-recursion-error).

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fh8z92Lw/1/)

working code snippet:

```js
var map, marker;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.520904, -0.107466),
    zoom: 17,
    draggable: false,
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-container"),
    mapOptions);

  var blueIco = {
    url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png",
    size: new google.maps.Size(55, 73),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(28, 72)
  };

  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.520904, -0.107466);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: latLng,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: blueIco,
    normalIcon: blueIco
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function(event) {
    this.setIcon(this.normalIcon);
    infowindow.close();
  });
  $('.location').on('click', function() {
    var latlonStr = $(this).data('location')
    var coords = latlonStr.split(",");
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[0], coords[1]);
    pan(latLng);
    if (marker && marker.setMap) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: latLng,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      icon: blueIco,
      normalIcon: blueIco
    });


  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function pan(latlon) {
  map.panTo(latlon)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-container" class="col-md-12 no-gutter" style="height:500px;"></div>
<a name="locations"></a>

<ul>
  <li><a class="location" data-location="52.240477,-0.902656">northampton</a>

  </li>
  <li><a class="location" data-location="51.454265,-0.97813">reading</a>

  </li>
  <li><a class="location" data-location="51.262251,-0.467252">surrey</a>

  </li>
  <li><a class="location" data-location="51.555774,-1.779718">swindon</a>

  </li>
  <li><a class="location" data-location="51.864211,-2.238033">gloucestershire</a>

  </li>
</ul>
```